# How to find the frequency bands of DWT signal transformation?

Tags: python, signal-processing, wavelet, dwt, pywavelets

I am newbie in Signal Processing, I want find out the frequency rang each of level outputted by a Daubechies  wavelet 'db4' transformation. The transformation is done with PyWavelets.
I'm working in python and the code below outputs 5 detail levels and 1 approximation however I'm not sure which frequency range each level describes.

```
data = pywt.wavedec(X_train_ch1_raw[0], 'db4', level=5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is trickier than it seems.

The short answer is: use pywt's `scale2freq` built-in function to return the frequency associated with a given wavelet at a given scale. For instance, the code below returns the frequency of the Daubechies 4 wavelet, at scale 5 (0.14285714285714285):

`import pywt
 pywt.scale2frequency('db4',5)`

You could get to the same result by computing the central frequency of your db4 wavelet (0.7142857142857143) and then dividing by the scale (5)

`import pywt
 pywt.central_frequency('db4')/5`

Please note that this **is not the actual central frequency of the signal**! This quantity is called a *pseudo-frequency* because it is independent from the signal being analyzed.

In order to recover the central frequency of the signal, you need to divide the pseudo-frequency by the sampling rate of the signal:

`import pywt
 pywt.scale2frequency('db4',5)/dt`

Where `dt` is your sampling rate.

I hope this helps!

PS: I suggest plotting the spectrum of the reconstructed signal to convince yourself that the central frequency matches the value output by the aforementioned analytical formula.

Comment: Top bloke! Central frequency will be good enough for what I'm after.